# Does C# support 'nested' procedures for e.g. yielding an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

Pseudo example

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() {

    List<MyEntity> before = MyEntityRepository.GetAll();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new IEnumerable<MyExtendedEntity>({
            before.ForEach(x =>
                yield return new ExtendedEntity {
                    Property1    = x.Property1,
                    Property2    = x.Property2,
                    ExtendedProp = ExtendedPropProvider.getExtended(x)
                })
         );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your example, why not to use just Select?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() {

List<MyEntity> before = MyEntityRepository.GetAll();
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
    before.Select(x => new ExtendedEntity 
    {
       Property1    = x.Property1,
       Property2    = x.Property2,
       ExtendedProp = ExtendedPropProvider.getExtended(x)
    }));
```

Comment: Wow, why didn't I thought about this? Simple and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't. It supports iterators and anonymous methods, but not anonymous iterators. See [this blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/24/iterator-blocks-part-seven-why-no-anonymous-iterators.aspx).

<strike>There might be another way to do what you want, but the code you posted doesn't really make sense... what are you trying to do?</strike> OK, I understand now... Eugene's answer should do what you want.